# Python, Flask, 'Hello World': No browser reaction

Tags: python, firefox, flask

I have pip-installed Flask and HTML5 on my Window-system. When I start the Hello World!-program with IDLE, I get a red message in the Python-Shell:

```
"* Running on xxxx://127.0.0.1:5000/". (xxxx = http)
```

And when I start it with app.run(debug=True) another red message appears:

```
"* Restarting with reloader".
```

My browser (Firefox) shows no reaction.
What can I do to get 'Hello World' in a new tab of Firefox?

The Code is:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

return and app.run are indended

Comment: provide the code please

Comment: The code is:from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

Comment: Can you update your question with the code ? Btw which url are you using on your browser ?

Answer (score 9):

You have to open a new tab with this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

Comment: @user3891230 if it solve your problem you can validate the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually open the page in your browser - it won't open itself. Open Firefox and navigate to

```
127.0.0.1:5000
```

(it's a URL)

When you run your code, it sits around waiting for a request from the user. When it gets a request, it'll return a response, and that's (sort of) what you see in your browser. Going to a URL is how you send that request - Flask will interpret anything sent to `127.0.0.1:5000` as a request, and try to match the URL to one of your `@app.route` decorators. For example, if you were to have a function decorated with `@app.route("/hello")`, then when you go to `127.0.0.1:5000/hello`, Flask would run that function to determine the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "<h1>Hello!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

refrence [Flask at first run: Do not use the development server in a production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025893/flask-at-first-run-do-not-use-the-development-server-in-a-production-environmen)

Answer (score -3):

```
 from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
    def hello():
        return "Hello World!"

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Try this, this works for me. Open your firefox browser and go to the address given in the output. ex: http://XXXX.X.X.X:5000/

Comment: I think he did wrong copy and past because he provide the same code in comments. And btw it don't works you have an indent problem