# Flask at first run: Do not use the development server in a production environment

Tags: python, flask

I installed the Flask plugin in PyCharm Community Edition and I just have this simple code in my flask app:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>Hello!</h1>'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And I get this message:

```
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead

* Restarting with stat
* Debugger is active!
* Debugger PIN: 123-456-789
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

Why am I getting this error when I run Flask?

---

<sub>A previous version of the message read "Do not use the development server in a production environment."</sub>

Answer (score 124, accepted):

As of Flask 2.2, the development server always shows this warning, it is not possible to disable it. The development server is not intended for use in production. It is not designed to be particularly efficient, stable, or secure. Use a production WSGI server instead. See [the deployment docs from Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/deploying/) for more information.

That warning is just a warning though, it's not an error preventing your app from running. If your app isn't working, there's something else wrong with your code.

That warning applies to the development server, not Flask itself. The Flask framework is appropriate for any type of application and deployment.

Answer (score 300):

For deploying an application to production, one option is to use Waitress, a production WSGI server.

Here is an example of using `waitress` in the code.

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "<h1>Hello!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Running the application:

```
$ python hello.py
```

---

Waitress also provides a command line utility `waitress-serve`. To use that, you can modify the code to the following:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "<h1>Hello!</h1>"

def create_app():
   return app
```

Then we can use `waitress-serve` as the following:

```
waitress-serve --port=8080 --call hello:create_app
```

---

And BTW, 8080 is the default port.

To validate the deployment, open a separate window:

```
% curl localhost:8080
<h1>Hello!</h1>%
```

Or directly in your browser http://localhost:8080/.

---

Other alternatives to deploy your app include Gunicorn and uWSGI. For more details, please refer to the [flask deploy doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/tutorial/deploy/).

Comment: Is there any difference between `serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)` and `waitress-serve --call flaskr:create_app`. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: There is any fundamental differences. `waitress-serve` is just a convenient command line runner. I personally would prefer the former since it is more documented.

Comment: Weren't you going to write: "There **isn't** any fundamental differences"?

Comment: Oh, I missed the most important word. lol. Yea, there aren't any fundamental differences.

Comment: What exactly is  "flaskr:create app"? If I have created a simple "test.py" in which there is one @api.route method, what should I pass as the command-line argument? Because obviously typing the same as your example did not work.

Comment: @DamnVegetables Thanks for the question. `flaskr` is the name of the file and `create_app` is the function to create the application. I will update my answer to clarify that.

Comment: I don't know if it's only me but I had to create a `def create_app():` surrounding all my code with a `return app` at the end, and instead of your `if create_app():` I did `if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run()` Maybe I have missed something from your example but anyway it works for me like that. I wanted to share if someone like me didn't understand. With your example I get `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`

Comment: @ZazOufUmI thanks a lot for pointing that out. It was a mistake from my last edit. I corrected it. It should be `def` instead `if`.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question on "why it happens", only points how to avoid the warning message...

Comment: @LeonardoPapais It is due to this line https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/6b0c8cdac1fb9bbec88de3a514907c19e372c72a/src/flask/cli.py#L649. We are not supposed to run the flask app directly for prod env. That's why it warms us.

Comment: `waitress` doesn't support `ssl` natively, you need to use a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 16):

Try gevent:

```
from flask import Flask
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Debug/Development
    # app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port="5000")
    # Production
    http_server = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

Note: Install gevent using pip install gevent

Answer (score 4):

If for some people (like me earlier) the above answers don't work, I think the following answer would work (for Mac users I think)
Enter the following commands to do flask run

```
$ export FLASK_APP=hello.py
$ export FLASK_ENV=development
$ flask run
```

Alternatively you can do the following (I haven't tried this but one resource online talks about it)

```
$ export FLASK_APP=hello.py
$ python -m flask run
```

source: [For more](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/master/server/)

Comment: The same solution was described earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51026060/2506522

Answer (score 3):

To avoid these messsages, inside the CLI (Command Line Interface), run these commands.

```
export FLASK_APP=app.py
export FLASK_ENV=development
export FLASK_DEBUG=0
flask run
```

Comment: FLASK_ENV is going to be deprecated.  FLASK_DEBUG=0 turns OFF debug mode, which may not be a good idea during development/testing.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on windows:

```
$env:FLASK_APP="flask_project.py"
$env:FLASK_ENV="development"
flask run
```

flask_project.py is on the same path as my virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the warning because the color red burns, then you can just change the warning from the source file without any side effects...you will still receive your http response status codes as normal.
Go into C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py and make the changes.
[image: command prompt]

Answer (score 0):

To Just Bypass the warning use below code , else follow : https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/deploying/

```
import functools
from typing import Callable, Any, Tuple, Dict
import werkzeug.serving

def _ansi_style_supressor(func: Callable[..., Any]) -> Callable[..., Any]:
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args: Tuple[Any, ...], **kwargs: Dict[str, Any]) -> Any:
        if args and isinstance(args[0], str) and args[0].startswith('WARNING: This is a development server.'):
            return ''
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

# Apply the suppressor to the _ansi_style function
werkzeug.serving._ansi_style = _ansi_style_supressor(werkzeug.serving._ansi_style)
```

Paste the above code on top of the file which run Flask.

The above code defines a decorator _ansi_style_supressor that takes a function as input and returns a modified function that suppresses the warning message only.