# having trouble deploying a flask api, react app to heroku

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, heroku, deployment

My file structure is as follows

```
api --> where all my flask api is 
build 
src
package.json
```

I have successfully made a git repository out of the api and pushed it to my heroku account.
I am having trouble deploying the front end with this file structure. Blog posts and youtube videos I have came across show deployment with the python file inside of the main folder and not structured in a different folder of its own.
I was wondering how I should go about deploying with this file structure. This is the first time I am deploying and I would be grateful if someone could walk me through it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my deployment of angular project with flask. But most of the procedure is same for react also. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62359734/11783181)

Keep Procfile, wsgi.py and runtime.txt in root along with package.json. Do changes in wsgi.py import statement.

Comment: I changed my folder structure but now again the api gets deployed but the react frontend doesn't. It gives me this error :The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: @AliNaji Check your routes or static file location you have set in flask app.