# serving flask app with waitress and docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, production, waitress

I am serving a flask app with docker but the `docker logs` command shows that the app is running on a `development` server. I want to serve this app with `waitress`.

The project is structured like this below. A `docker-compose.yml` file to build the image, expose the port and run the `manage.py` file

**`docker-compose.yml`**

```
  web:
    build: .
    image: web
    container_name: web
    ports:
      - 8080:5000
    command: python manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0
```

**`manage.py`** file imports the `create_app` and provides it into `FLaskGroup`

```
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup
from project.server import create_app

app = create_app()
cli = FlaskGroup(create_app=create_app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

**`project/server/__init__.py`** file imports the `main_blueprint` and registers it.

```
from project.server.main.views import main_blueprint
from flask import Flask
import os

def create_app(script_info=None):

    app = Flask(
        __name__,
        template_folder="../client/templates",
        static_folder="../client/static",
    )

    app_settings = os.getenv("APP_SETTINGS")
    app.config.from_object(app_settings)

    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    app.shell_context_processor({"app": app})

    return app
```

**`project/server/main/views.py`**

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint, jsonify, request

main_blueprint = Blueprint("main", __name__,)

@main_blueprint.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def home():
    return render_template("pages/home.html")


@main_blueprint.route("/test", methods=["GET"])
def parse():
    return jsonify({"result": "test"}), 202
```

How can I modify the existing code to serve the `flask` app with `waitress`? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it running by changing the `docker-compose.yml` file:

**`command`**

`python manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0` to `waitress-serve --call "project.server:create_app"`

**`port`**

`8080:5000` to `8080:8080`

**`docker-compose.yml`** file looks like below now:

```
  web:
    build: .
    image: web
    container_name: web
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    command: waitress-serve --call "project.server:create_app"
```

Comment: Using waitress in code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54381386/251674

Answer (score 0):

You run using `python manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0`, which uses the classic `flask run`. You should use waitress commands to run your app.

[This doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/deploy/#run-with-a-production-server) might help you.

Comment: How can I refactor this `python manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0` for waitress serve command?

Comment: `waitress-serve --call 'yourappname:create_app'`

Comment: I actually did this before but it didn't work. I had to change the port as well just now, and it worked. Although, thanks.

Comment: Well yeah, you had to change the port ... did you read the doc ?

Comment: I did read the doc before posting the question. But the port change had to happen in the docker-compose.yml file.